# PHP - Reorder array to match the order of another array

Tags: php, arrays

I have 1 array that has the right values that I need but it is out of order. I then have another array with the same keys and it is in the right order but the values are not what I need.

Here is my first array with the correct values but is out of order:

```
Array
(
    [countTotal] => 7268
    [zip] => 
    [yearName] => 
    [countZipRadius] => 
    [Acura] => 1334
    [Cadillac] => 511
    [Ford] => 5423
)
```

Here is my second array with the right order but the wrong values:

```
Array
(
    [countZipRadius] => 0
    [zip] => 1
    [yearName] => 2
    [Acura] => 3
    [Cadillac] => 4
    [Ford] => 5
    [countTotal] => 6
)
```

I am trying to figure out a way to create a new array with the right values from array 1 but that is in the order of array 2.

I have been playing with it for awhile and cannot seem to get it.

Any help would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the ordering you use? Is it a custom ordering?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$c = array();
foreach (array_keys($b) as $k) {
    $c[k] = $a[k];
}
```

Comment: Exactly that. Instead of trying to order the existing array, simply create a new one. You have to make sure however that your arrays have the same keys. Otherwise information might get lost.

Comment: actually a solution with a fixed parameter name order would be better. but therefore one would need more insight into the code. like $keys = array( 'a', 'b', 'c'); foreach ($keys as $k) ; that would be independent of the array $b

Answer (score 1):

You could use php's `array_multisort` function:

```
$original = array(
    'countTotal' => 7268,
    'zip' => '',
    'yearName' => '',
    'countZipRadius' => '',
    'Acura' => 1334,
    'Cadillac' => 511,
    'Ford' => 5423,
    );

$right = array(
    'countZipRadius' => 0,
    'zip' => 1,
    'yearName' => 2,
    'Acura' => 3,
    'Cadilac' => 4,
    'Ford' => 5,
    'countTotal' => 6
);

//make sure both arrays are in the same order
ksort($original);
ksort($right);

array_multisort($right, $original);

print_r($original);
```

When you give it two arrays with the same number of elements it sorts both arrays, based on the order of the first array - in this case the 0, 1, 2, 3, etc. values in `$right`

Comment: Thanks! array_multisort has to be my favorite function

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a New Array (Array C)
2. Use a FOR loop to go through Array B
3. For each value in Array B, get the value with the same key from Array A and set Array C append those values to Array C.  This will put them in the correct order in C.

Answer (score 0):

Using scones' method:

```
$original = array(
    'countTotal' => 7268,
    'zip' => '',
    'yearName' => '',
    'countZipRadius' => '',
    'Acura' => 1334,
    'Cadillac' => 511,
    'Ford' => 5423,
    );
$right = array(
    'countZipRadius' => 0,
    'zip' => 1,
    'yearName' => 2,
    'Acura' => 3,
    'Cadilac' => 4,
    'Ford' => 5,
    'countTotal' => 6
);
foreach ($right as $key => $value) {
    $new[$key] = $original[$key];
}
print_r($new);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array('a' => 100, 'b' => '5');

$newArray = array_combine(array_keys($array), range(0, count($array) - 1));

var_dump($newArray);
```